# Graph API to update Azure AD group's members properties

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

Is there any **graph API** to update Azure AD group's members properties?
Please do let me know the required **AD roles** as well for executing such API, if there is one.

> I need to update one of the custom attribute's property which is common across
> all the members in that specific group.

I am able to `update the individual members using member ID but not as a whole`.

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In my humble opinion, I reviewed the API list and I didn't found an API which could update member properties of a group, so I'm afraid we have to [list members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) first then [batch update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/batch-requests?tabs=csharp) member's property.